# Python/Curses: Nothing happens on first key press

Tags: python, curses

The code:

```
from curses import curs_set, KEY_RESIZE, newwin, resize_term, wrapper
from curses.panel import *


VERSION = '0.0.0a'


class Editor:
    def __init__(self, stdscr):
        curs_set(0)
        self.screen = stdscr
        self.max_rows, self.max_cols = self.screen.getmaxyx()
        self.panel = {
            'titlebar': EditorPanel(1, self.max_cols, 0, 0),
            'menubar': EditorPanel(1, self.max_cols-1, 2, 1)
        }
        self.panel['titlebar'].addstr(0, 0, f'Yedit {VERSION}')
        self.panel['menubar'].addstr(0, 0, 'File | Edit | View | Help')
        self.update()

    def input_handler(self):
        ch = self.screen.getch()
        if ch == ord('q'):
            return False
        elif ch == KEY_RESIZE:
            resize_term(*self.screen.getmaxyx())
            self.update()
        elif ch == ord('m'):
            # print(ch)
            self.panel['menubar'].toggle_visibility()

        return True

    def update(self):
        for key in self.panel:
            for argv in self.panel[key].text:
                self.panel[key].window.addstr(*argv)
            self.panel[key].window.refresh()
        update_panels()


class EditorPanel:
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, y, x):
        self.window = newwin(rows, cols, y, x)
        self.panel = new_panel(self.window)
        self.text = []

    def addstr(self, y, x, text):
        self.text.append((y, x, text))

    def toggle_visibility(self):
        if self.panel.hidden():
            self.panel.show()
        else:
            self.panel.hide()
        self.window.refresh()
        update_panels()


def main(stdscr):
    yedit = Editor(stdscr)
    while yedit.input_handler():
        continue


wrapper(main)
```

The problem:
When the 'm' key is pressed, it toggles the visibility of the panel, but absolutely nothing happens on the first press of 'm.' The `print(ch)` statement was included to test this. I've omitted a final `else` statement I used to verify that `ch` wasn't some unexpected value. In contrast, pressing 'q' exits the program as expected on the first key press.

What is going on?

Comment: I would add a "elif print(error)".  As it is, if 'm' is mangled in some way, it would not print and you wouldn't know why.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the last line . . . my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got refreshes sprinkled all over the place in your code. I'm not sure exactly why the first key press isn't working, but if you handle the refresh in a single location in your event loop like...

```
def input_handler(self):
    self.screen.refresh()
    ch = self.screen.getch()
    ...
```

and remove the other calls to "refresh", the hide functionality functions properly

Comment: that's redundant, since getch does a refresh

Comment: yeah- maybe so. I fiddled with it to learn a bit about curses, but I do _not_ actually understand why that change worked haha.